# Android status bar icon

Tags: android, icons, statusbar

How do I put an icon into the android status bar? I don't want any notifications to be associated with it. Just the icon and nothing more.

Thanks

Comment: The GMail app can do that (with the sync icon). Is it using some private, special API to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to put an icon in the status bar is to start a notification.

Comment: I have read this answer in many places but I dont think it is correct. I use Llama (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama) and it does set a status bar icon but with no notification. I don't know how they do it though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to add them but read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html) on designing them.

Also, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e74z0_Z5QWI