# Icon in Android StatusBar without visible notification?

Tags: android, notifications

I want to show my users that service is running.

I saw this thread: [Android status bar icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380270/android-status-bar-icon)

Best answer says:

> The only way to put an icon in the status bar is to start a
>   notification.

But what if I don't want to display notification. I just want an icon. Is that possible? Can I hide notification somehow?

Comment: No it's not possible

Comment: Here's your answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11294525/4671372
This will always show your icon, but also and notification. But you can just set notification text to empty, and show only app icon.